# Detect Class Inheritance in t4 template

Tags: c#, t4

Can you detect a class' inherited properties in a t4 template?

I have two classes like so:

```
public class User : ManagedRecord
{
   public int UserId { get; set;}
   public string UserName { get; set;}
}

public abstract class ManagedRecord
{
   public int Deleted { get; set;}
   public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set;}
}
```

When the t4 template creates fields based on User, it will place the ManagedRecord fields first, then the fields for User.

Is there a way to detect the inherited class fields so I can handle them differently?

The t4 template is for an ASP.NET MVC 5 edit page template, which creates form fields based on the class that is used.

The t4 code looks like:

```
<#@ template language="C#" HostSpecific="True" #>
<#@ output extension=".cshtml" #>
<#@ include file="Imports.include.t4" #>
@model <#= ViewDataTypeName #>
<#
    string boolType = "System.Boolean";
    int tabIndex = 1;
    bool autofocus = true;
    Version requiredMvcVersion = new Version("5.1.0.0");
    bool isControlHtmlAttributesSupported = MvcVersion >= requiredMvcVersion;


foreach (PropertyMetadata property in ModelMetadata.Properties) {
if (property.Scaffold && !property.IsAssociation) {
#>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.<#= property.PropertyName #>)
<#
}
#>
```

Comment: "When the t4 template creates fields based on User" which t4 template? You didn't show any code for your T4 template.

Comment: @Evk It is a MVC edit page template. I can add the code for that template but I'm also willing to mold that code to whatever would allow me to handle the inherited fields differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that worked in my scenario. You can decorate the properties to indicate that you don't want to scaffold the columns.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public abstract class ManagedRecord
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public DateTime CreatedDate{ get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    }
}
```